# Fullcalendar detect right-click on empty time slots on agenda views

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using Adam Shaw's fullcalendar 2.1.1 JS library to implement a calendar in my webapp. 
I need to react to right-clicks on certain elements. I already got it to respond on right clicks on events and days by binding the "mousedown" event in the `dayRender` and `eventRender` callbacks.

But, I also need to react on right-clicks on empty slots in the agenda views. `dayClicked` is not triggered on right click and there are no other useable render callbacks documented. 
Does anybody know how I could implement a right-click listener on empty slots in agenda views?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `onmousedown` to each day:

```
onmousedown="CustomContext()"
```

then in the function something like:

```
function CustomContext() {    
    var e = window.event;        
    var x=e.clientX;        
    var y=e.clientY;

    if (e.which === 3 || e.button === 2) {
         //right click happened        
    }    
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't have access to the days to bind the listener to them. I used 'renderEvent' and 'renderDay' to bind a listener to events and whole days which works, but this listener doesn't get triggered for timeslots in the agenda views.

Comment: If you know the ID of each of the days then you could add the customcontext to the container then add e.target.id to the function  then check that you are on the day.